CircleCI fails on step that does nothing
I have a CircleCI step that takes up a list of changed files on a git PR, checks for specific extensions, and then runs a command on each of those files, it looks something like this:
command: |
  git diff main..$(git branch --show-current) --name-only --diff-filter=d | grep '\(\.rb\|\.rake\)$' | xargs --no-run-if-empty bundle exec rubocop -a

Basically, the first portion of the command (git diff -> grep) will give xargs a list of file names. However, if this list is empty xargs --no-run-if-empty will not run the command at all. When this scenario happens, it returns a code 1 on CircleCI which fails the step. How can I make it so it returns 0 on that case?
UPDATE:
CircleCI puts this at the top of my command: #!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
I rewrote the command into this, and seems to be working, although can't say this is the best solution, I'm not very knowledgeable on CircleCI nor Bash:
files=$(git diff main..$(git branch --show-current) --name-only --diff-filter=d | grep '\(\.rb\|\.rake\)$') || true
if [ -z "$files" ]; then
      exit 0
else
      echo $files | xargs bundle exec rubocop -a
 fi


Your diagnosis is likely wrong. I just tried  xargs --no-run-if-empty ls </dev/null, and this sets exit code 0, not 1. Hence an empty input can't be the cause. I suggest that you insert in your pipe, just before the xargs, a tee command, i.e. ... | tee inp.txt | xargs ..., and then verify whether inp.txt really has size zero (i.e. stat inp.txt). BTW, try to reproduce the exit code problem outside of CircleCI.

After further investigation, I found out CircleCI puts this at the top of each step:
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail, which I believe is the reason why it ends with code 1 when git diff/grep throws back an empty list

Good point. If grep does not find any line matching the pattern, it sets exit code 1. Of course this design decision of CircleCI is pretty stupid.  I suggest that you wrap your whole pipeline into a separate script (child process), which you then call from CircleCI. In this way, you have full control.
